# Prevent Tomcat7 Maven Plugin from Logging Upload Progress

Tags: maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am using the Tomcat7 Maven plugin to deploy an application to a test server in our continuous integration process. (We are using Bamboo) When the plugin runs it gives the user feedback on the upload progress. This is ok when running in a command line because it just keeps updating the same line. However, when running in Bamboo it logs tons of useless lines giving progress updates on the upload. (10,000+ lines for a 20MB application)

```
build   13-May-2014 09:02:57    2/19722 KB   
build   13-May-2014 09:02:57    4/19722 KB   
build   13-May-2014 09:02:57    6/19722 KB   
build   13-May-2014 09:02:57    8/19722 KB   
build   13-May-2014 09:02:57    10/19722 KB   
build   13-May-2014 09:02:57    12/19722 KB   
build   13-May-2014 09:02:57    14/19722 KB
```

This isn't a serious problem, but it really clutters the build logs. Is there a way to make the Tomcat7 Maven plugin not log upload progress?

Comment: Have you tried to use `mvn -B ...` ?

Comment: I just tried -B and even -q, but it still outputs the progress.

Comment: I didn't figure it out, but instead I am using Bamboo's Tomcat plugin to deploy the application so I don't run into this problem.

Comment: So this mean the plugin itself does the logging and does not pay attention to the -B option.

Comment: According to their [bug tracking site](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-176) this issue is fixed in version 2.2. I was using 2.0 so switching to 2.2 fixed this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum it up: Use at least version 2.2 of tomcat7-maven-plugin.

```xml
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
      </plugin>
```

Then run Maven with `-B` or `-q`.

```
mvn -B clean package tomcat7:redeploy
```